# Reputation changes from accepting answers to questions are not included in reputation results

Tags: bug, users, api-v2.2, reputation

When querying the [/users/{ids}/reputation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users) API route, the results don't include the +2 reputation changes from accepting answers.

None of the reputation results from [my own reputation history](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/reputation-on-users#page=1&pagesize=100&ids=1288&filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) have a `vote_type` of "accepts" and a `post_type` of "question", despite the fact that I've accepted 69 answers to my questions.
I've also looked for reputation changes of +2 and looked at the reputation histories of lower-reputation users to verify that these reputation changes are missing from the results.

Comment: Re-confirmed this is still an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up working around this by using the `question_count` and `accept_rate` fields from the [/users/{ids}](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids) API route, then just calculating the reputation for accepting answers. Note that `question_count` is not included in the default filter, so you have to add it in.

Note: This isn't exact because of self-accepted answers, but it should be close for most users.